# Socket sending work only the first time and after it throw an SocketException

Tags: java

Here's my client code:

```
public static void main(final String[] args)
{
    try (final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in))
    {
        System.out.println("Type:");

        try (final Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 80);
            final DataOutputStream dout = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()))
        {
            while (scanner.hasNext())
            {
                dout.writeUTF(scanner.nextLine());
                dout.flush();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

and here's my server:

```
public ConnectorData()
{
    try
    {
        _server = new ServerSocket(80);
    }
    catch (final Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            try (final Socket socket = _server.accept();
                final DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream()))
            {
                System.out.println(dis.readUTF());
            }
        }
        catch (final Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

it works fine in the first message but when i type again in console and hit enter it freezes and then i send again third time and it throw me an:

```
java SocketException: An established connection was aborted by the software in your host machine
```

What is it for? Where is my mistake? I basically want to type in chat anything i want and when i press enter to send in server and print it out on console.

Answer (score 0):

Compare and contrast:

- Your client creates a `Socket` connected to your server, then sends a bunch of `String`s through it.
- Your server accepts a connection from a client to establish a `Socket`, reads ***one*** `String` from it, and then goes back to repeat the whole process.

It is not surprising, then, that the first line you type at the client is transferred successfully, but subsequent ones are not.  The server's behavior needs to match the client: it needs to keep reading data from the same socket until the client is done sending.  If you want it to afterward loop back to try to accept another connection then that's a separate matter.

Comment: So how i should adjust the server? Remove the while(true)? or What. I guess my client is good cause i create 1 socket and then i use this socket to send whatever i want.

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors, you need a second loop *inside* the inner `try`, in which you read multiple lines from the socket.  Were it me, I would probably factor that out to another method.

Comment: There is also the question of when to stop reading.  If everyone cooperates nicely and there are no network or machine problems, then you can probably just read until the client closes the socket on its end.  That may be enough for this exercise.  In the real world, however, a robust server needs to accommodate all manner of error conditions, including some that for all intents and purposes make the client just disappear.

Comment: I got confuse. I don't really understand what i should do. I get what you mean but in terms of coding i am confused. I see code and i try find my mistake (the logic) but i see nothing wrong. I normally should store the "Client" somewhere and read from him until it's closed but i don't know how to do properly the logic part not the programming.

Comment: @TheLegendBeginsTremors, then I recommend stepping through the server code with a Java debugger to better understand the program flow.  This is a very useful general skill, so the time to learn it will be well spent.  Most Java IDEs have integrated debuggers.  The most important point here is that when control exits the `try (final Socket socket = _server.accept(); ...` statement, the socket is closed.  The server must avoid closing the socket until it has received all the data the client is going to send (or as much as the server is willing to accept, at least).